# I'm trying to .Find() a TextArea inside a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <div id='bla'>
   <textarea type='text' style='text-align:center; color:black; width:90px; border:1px     
    solid transparent; font-size:11px; margin:2px'>this is a test</textarea>
 </div>​​​​​​​​​​​​

 alert($('bla').find('textarea').css('border'))
```

but for some reason this returns 'undefined' any ideas why? I'm defining a border inside that style... :/

jsfiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/yWgqD/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Missed the ID selector (`#`) before `bla`...

Instead, use the following:

```
alert($('#bla textarea').css('border'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `#` ID selector:

```
$("#bla").find("textarea").css("border");
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector only won't cut it, you forgot the dom ready part too.

```
$(function() {
    alert($('#bla').find('textarea').css('border'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yWgqD/1/

Also as selector this is cleaner

$('#bla textarea')